# How can I test for multiple browsers at once in browserstack through node?

Tags: browserstack

I'm a beginner to browserStack and wanted to know if I can test for multiple browsers at once. I have an account which provides 100 minutes of free service. I'm using it to test a small application in Chrome(below are the capabilities)

````
    'browserName': 'Chrome',
    'browser_version': '62.0',
    'os': '62.0',
    'os_version': '10',
    'resolution': '1366x768',
    'browserstack.user': 'xxx',
    'browserstack.key': 'yyy',
    'name': 'Bstack-[Node] Sample Test',
    'browserstack.debug': true,
    'browserstack.local': true,
    'acceptSslCerts': true
}```
 It would be of great help if anyone insisted me on having it to extend for multiple browsers and different versions in a single execution.
````

Comment: Which programming language and which testing tool you are using?

Comment: nodejs, Browserstack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MakeFile with multiple platform or browser combinations as parallel jobs and then run the MakeFile. This is the easiest way to run tests in parallel in Browserstack. I have done this using java it works as charm. And MakeFile works with any programming language. 
Below is a sample MakeFile.

`browserstack_parallel:
    make -j bs_windows_10_firefox_69 bs_windows_8.1_ie_11`

`bs_windows_10_firefox_69:
    mvn test -Dbs_local_testing=false -Dbs_browser=Firefox -Dbs_browser_version=69.0 -Dbs_os=Windows -Dbs_os_version=10 -Dbs_selenium_version=3.141.59`

`bs_windows_8.1_ie_11:
    mvn test -Dbs_local_testing=false -Dbs_browser=IE -Dbs_browser_version=11.0 -Dbs_os=Windows -Dbs_os_version=8.1 -Dbs_selenium_version=3.141.59`

For running this MakeFile run the command
`make browserstack_parallel`

Answer (score 0):

Used parallel testing which would test for multiple browsers in a single execution